# Running tasks in AWS Lambda background

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, promise, aws-api-gateway

Its possible a lambda function return a value to api-gateway when lambda still run a promise?

```
function wait() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>'Hello', 3000));
}


function handler(event){
    wait.then(console.log);
    return {statusCode: 200};
}
```

Comment: i want to see this log in cloud watch when the task is finished

Comment: No, what you should do instead is tell the thing on the invoking side to not wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  When the handler function ends, any other running threads are halted.

I linked an article below that may be interesting to you.  It appears that if the Lambda container is reused, it is possible to have those halted background threads to be resumed but this wouldn't necessarily be guaranteed.

Resources:

- [What Happens to Running Threads When a Lambda Finishes Executing?](https://medium.com/@zaccharles/what-happens-to-running-threads-when-a-lambda-finishes-executing-312a6f5757b4#:%7E:text=Lambda%20will%20call%20the%20EntryPoint,and%20found%20that%20it%27s%20true!)